# How to use uploaded file info to fill in form fields

Tags: django

I am trying to create a file upload form where a user uploads a file and then I do some processing on it.  After processing the file, I want to redirect the user to another form that is partially filled in already from the data I gathered from that file.

I've been reading the docs and found something on multipart forms, but don't know if this is what I should be looking into.  I've found example code on uploading files and how to build forms (love Django docs!), but I'm not sure how to tie the two together.

A potential problem I've thought of is how to make sure that a user doesn't somehow skip to the other form without uploading a file.  The second form should only be accessible after uploading the file and having it verified for the info I need from it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to store the parsed information from the file in the session. That way you can check when displaying the form if the data exists in the session, and if not redirect back to the upload form. If it does exist, you can simply use it as the initial data for the form.

Comment: Thanks, I will do some digging through the docs and try this out.  Will mark as correct later on.